# Python receive push notifications like a browser

Tags: python, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to make python receive a web push notification like a browser?

I have a web page with Firebase cloud messaging subscription service (FCM JavaScript client)
I need to somehow receive notifications on my python program running on Windows PC.

One idea was to open a selenium chrome browser and receive notifications through that but I didn't find a way to receive data from notifications, also I'm trying to log all Windows notifications with Auto Hotkey and read the log file for my purpose but neither if this methods are time and resource reasonable.

So is there any way to achieve this purpose?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pyfcm/ should help

Comment: Maybe you can start a web server in Python, get data from notifications using JavaScript and send it to the server?

Comment: Yeah @papercut that should work, although some wiring will be required. I think using Avinash Thakur's pyfcm should do better. Thank you both!